# R: how to extract random effects from nlmer output

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

```
library(lme4)
startvec <- c(Asym = 200, xmid = 725, scal = 350)
(nm1 <- nlmer(circumference ~ SSlogis(age, Asym, xmid, scal) ~ Asym|Tree,
              Orange, start = startvec))
> summary(nm1)$varcor
 Groups   Name Std.Dev.
 Tree     Asym 31.646  
 Residual       7.843
```

I'm trying to extract the standard deviation of `Asym`'s random effect (e.g. 31.646). But I've tried `summary(nm1)$varcor$Std.Dev.` and `summary(nm1)$varcor[1, 3]` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stddev` is an attribute

```
suppressWarnings(as.vector(attr(summary(nm1)$varcor$Tree, "stddev")))
#[1] 31.64632
```

If we check the `str` of

```
str(summary(nm1)$varcor)
#List of 1
# $ Tree: num [1, 1] 1001
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : chr "Asym"
#  .. ..$ : chr "Asym"
#  ..- attr(*, "stddev")= Named num 31.6
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Asym"
#  ..- attr(*, "correlation")= num [1, 1] 1
#  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. .. ..$ : chr "Asym"
#  .. .. ..$ : chr "Asym"
# - attr(*, "sc")= num 7.84
# - attr(*, "useSc")= logi TRUE
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "VarCorr.merMod"
```

it is a `list` with 'Tree' as the single element.  So we extract 'Tree' by either doing `$Tree` or `[[1]]` or `[["Tree"]]` and then extract the attribute 'stddev'